# fsck on a hardware RAID5

Tags: boot, raid, fsck

My Ubuntu 14.04 server won't boot properly and I want to check the hard drives with fsck to make sure everything is ok. I can boot into a systemRescueCD no problem. 
The server has 4 HD using a hardware RAID5 system. 
The main problem I have is I don't know what the names partitions of the virtual drives of the RAID are. 
Normally I would do something like this:

```
# fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

Now I get an error:

```
no such file or directory while opening /dev/sda1
```

/dev/sda1 does exist, but is part of the raid system, so I need to find out, what the name of the virtual partitions is, right? (There are two, root and storage).

The information should be in /etc/fstab if I understand correctly, but I can't access that file on the filesystem on the hard drives or can I?

Any ideas on how to check my RAID virtual disks?

Edit:
I am on a liveCD so proc/mounts, will not give me the desired HD info. 
I think I am looking for something like that, which would be found in /etc/fstab of my file system, but I can't access that file.

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/isw_ddahfidcda_Volume0p5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_ddahfidcda_Volume0p1 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/isw_ddahfidcda_Volume0p6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Do you have anything under `/dev/mapper`?